# How do I connect to the localhost of a docker container (from inside the container)

Tags: node.js, docker, blockchain

I have a nodejs app that connects to a blockchain on the same server. Normally I use 127.0.0.1 + the port number (each chain gets a different port).

I decided to put the chain and the app in the same container, so that the frontend developers don't have to bother with setting up the chain.

However, When I build the image the chain should start. When I run the image it isn't. Furthermore, when I do go in the container and try to run it manually it says "besluitChain2@xxx.xx.x.2:PORT". So I thought instead of 127.0.0.1 I needed to connect to the port on 127.0.0.2, but that doesn't seem to work.

I'm sure connecting like this isn't new, and should work the same with a database. Can anyone help? The first piece of advice would be how to debug these images, because I have no idea where it goes wrong.

here is my dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
ADD workfolder/app /root/applications/app
ADD .multichain /root/.multichain
RUN npm install \
    && apt-get upgrade -q -y \
        && apt-get dist-upgrade -q -y \
        && apt-get install -q -y wget curl \
        && apt-get clean \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
        && cd /tmp \
        && wget http://www.multichain.com/download/multichain-1.0-beta-1.tar.gz \
        && tar -xvzf multichain-1.0-beta-1.tar.gz \
        && cd multichain-1.0-beta-1 \
        && mv multichaind multichain-cli multichain-util /usr/local/bin \
        && cd /tmp \
        && rm -Rf multichain*
RUN multichaind Chain -daemon
RUN cd /root/applications/app && npm install
CMD cd /root/applications/app && npm start
EXPOSE 8080
```

btw due to policies I can only connect to the server at port 80 to check if it works. When I run the docker image I can go to my /api-docs but not to any of the endpoints where I start interacting with the blockchain.

Comment: What are you doing in your CMD or `docker run` to start the blockchain?

Comment: sudo docker run -d -p 80:8080 <image name>

Comment: You need tell docker what programs you wanna start. You can accomplish that with the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` in Dockerfile. Do you have something there?

Comment: yeah I think I mixed up RUN and CMD, I will try that. But as suggested below I might split the chain from the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I decided to put the chain and the app in the same container

That was a mistake, I think.

Docker is not a virtual machine. It's a virtual application or process instance.

A Docker container runs a linux distro under the hood, but this is a detail that should be ignored when thinking about the purpose of Docker.

You should think of a Docker container as a single application process, not as a full virtual machine to run generally run multiple processes. This is evidenced by the way Docker will shut the container down once the main process shuts down (the process with PID 1).

I've got a longer post about this, here: https://derickbailey.com/2016/08/29/so-youre-saying-docker-isnt-a-virtual-machine/

Additionally, the `RUN multichaind` instruction in your dockerfile doesn't run the chain in your image / container. It tells the image to run this instruction during the build process.

A Dockerfile is a list of instructions for building an image. The wording here is important. An image is not executed, it is built. An image is a static, immutable template from which a Container is executed.

> RUN multichaind Chain -daemon

By putting this `RUN` instruction in your image, you are temporarily starting the chain, but it is immediately halted (forcefully) when the image layer is done building. It will not remain running, because an image is not executed, it is built.

My advice is to put the chain in a separate image.

You'll have one image for the chain, and one for the node.js app.

You can use docker-compose to make it easier to run containers from both of these at the same time. Or you can run containers manually from them. Either way, you need two images.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation! will try that. However, this leads to the problem which lead me to putting it all in 1 image: How do I connect the app  from one container to the chain in the other container? In the past I just connected to 127.0.0.1:<chainport>

Comment: docker creates a default virtual network in which is places each container. you can access each container by name from other containers. if you have a container named "chain", then the dns name you would use is "chain". so in your other container you would access "chain:<port>". docker-compose also has configuration settings for all of this, and then there are more advanced topics like "service discovery" to handle this as well